# Is using Hub sites the new way of having sub-sites

Tags: sharepoint-online, team-sites, community-site, modern-team-site, hub-site

I am working on a new sharepoint online project. and we need to build the following:

1. Have a main intranet site where users can publish news, events and general documents and templates.
2. To have separate sites or sub-sites for each department. Such as HR, IT,  Finance, etc.

Now I was planning to follow the traditional way of doing things, mainly by:

1. Create a new classic team site (mainly to use the built-in root site collection).
2. To create separate classic team sub-sites for our departments.

But recently I read about Hub sites, and it is been mentioned that using hub sites should be the new/modern way of having sub-sites.

So I am not sure if for my above case I should follow having classic team site and classic sub-sites? OR I should use Hub sites and have departments' site collections that are linked to the hub site?

second point. one of the main benefits i usually get from using site collection and sub-sites, is that columns and content types created at the root site (site collection) will be available to all the sub-sites without having to set content type hubs or any things else, also i have the ability to have a sub-site which inherit from its root site, finally i also have the ability to have sub-sites of each sub-site. so i am not sure if these features/capabilities are offered for us when we use site collections linked to Hub Sites?

Answer (score 7):

Certainly, the standard recommendation moving forward would be to use modern sites and a flat structure, rather than subsites and/or classic sites. You're right, this changes how we approach things like content types.

The content type story is an interesting one these days:

- Content type hubs haven't been updated recently, nor have they been talked about at any recent conference, that I'm aware of
- MS seems to have decided that they like developers to be involved for these scenarios, as guidance points to resources such as the PNP dev tools, which certainly provide simple mechanisms to deploy virtually any sharepoint asset to site collections, including site columns and content types
- Site scripts allow us to deploy content types and site columns when the site is created, no hub site needed. (site scripts involve JSON and powershell, so again, some developer skill is needed here)

That said, there are some interesting benefits of flat structures, including permissions. Subsites per department often means breaking permission inheritance, which many users find confusing to administer. Flat structures mean that each site simply has permissions applied directly, without dealing with the mess of breaking inheritance.

Comment: Thanks fro the reply... so let say if we chose to have site collections linked to a hub site, then these site collections (un-like having sub-sites) will not have any direct link to their hub site in respect to site columns,content types & permissions?? is my point valid ? as using the traditional way , when i add a site column at the root site, i can automatically use the site column at the sub-sites, as this column will be referenced there, same apply to content type.. but in Flatt structures these types of linked are not part of the structure ??

Comment: Correct! The use of a hub site does not automatically cause site content types to be published - a hub site is not a content type publishing hub site. If you use a hub site, and want to use consistent content types throughout, you need to use another mechanism, such as a content type hub, site script, powershell, or 3rd party tool.

Comment: now those tools will mainly/only allow us to copy the content type and site columns across site collections ? is this correct? but still Physically & Logically those site columns and site content types are being managed separately on each site collection? is my point valid? i already have a migration tool named "sharegate" where i can easily copy content types and site columns across site collections,, but at the end each content type and each site column  is stored/managed separately Physically & Logically.. is this correct?

Comment: ShareGate is a great option for this, but yes, ultimately with any of these tools, the content types are separate: they are copied to each site, but each is a separate copy.

Comment: so in flat structures we need to set our minds (specifically the developers who came from classic experience) that site columns, site content types and site permissions will be Physically & Logically managed separately, regardless if we use tools to copy site columns and content types or we manually do the copy?? is this valid?

Comment: In classic mode, we certainly could have still used the multiple site collections, and which then presented the same issues. So, this is not new, just the scale of it is new. But yes, regardless of the method (manual in the browser, powershell, ShareGate, site script, content type hub, etc.), content type "sales document" in site collection 1 is a fundamentally a separate content type than "sales document" in site collection 2. We use the aformentioned tools to keep them in sync, but fundamentally, each is stored in its own site collection

Comment: My corporation is in the middle of a large SPO deployment and we've been assigned some Microsoft engineers as resources. I asked this question of them back when we were in the initial planning stages and this answer mirrors the response they provided me. The future of the Microsoft environment is groups (office unified groups) for every possible collection of users, site collections for every workspace, and hub sites tying them together.

Comment: That was last year's answer. Today, the answer is Teams for collaboration and communication sites for ... communication. ;)

Comment: @Mike2500 when i am comparing the re-usability of site columns and site content types, i am comparing 1) having a classic team site which have classic team sub-sites, 2) and having modern team sites collection for each department that is linked to a hub site.. where having the second option means the department site collections will not be sharing any content type and site columns, unlike having the departments as sub-sites where they will be sharing their parent site collections' components.. hope this clarify my point

Comment: @BrianR thanks for the reply.. can you explain your reply in more details please? so the question what are the differences between having a workspace and having a collection of users ? and when we talk about having sites representing departments, then are we talking about sub-sites? or modern team site collections linked through a hub site??

Comment: I understand your scenario, and that's what my answer addresses

Comment: @SharePointTestDev - The way Microsoft explained it to me is that sub-sites are essentially dead. They still exist for legacy purposes but everything purpose that would have required a subsite in pre-2016 Sharepoint will now get its own site collection which, in turn, creates an Office Group, Teams channel, etc. Projects, organizational units, collections of people with the same role (i.e. developers), special interest groups, social groups - everyone gets a group (read: Office Group) and all the accompanying features that entails, which includes a site collection.

Comment: Brian, They're "dead", but MS just added the capability of creating modern subsites, and certainly organizations with existing subsites can expect to see them continue to function as-is.

Comment: @Mike2500 i was just reading about the limitation of creating modern team sites.. so did MS announced that we can create modern team sub-sites? can you provide any link ?

Comment: See the announcement here: https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/Microsoft-SharePoint-Blog/Updates-to-SharePoint-self-service-site-creation/ba-p/218971, and this should simply be enabled in your tenant. Simply see the list of templates when creating a subsite.

Comment: @Mike2500  thanks for the link, i think it is a grey area, as most of the current modules in sharepoint online, now the link mentioned that they add the ability to add modern team sites (mainly team site with modern UI),, but they also mentioned that MS advice companies to use Hub Sites + flat structure.. but they are still allowing us to create sub-sites as subs-sites have been here for many years, and if they disable creating them then this will not be a valid action for many companies who are investing in  SharePoint sub-sites, of course this is my opinion... i do not work for MS

Answer (score 1):

Another way to approach this is: how much risk is acceptable in my project ?

The flat model and hub sites gives us a lot out of the box, however once we hit the boundries, we hit them at full speed, and only a very limited number of the old tricks we know is available in Modern SharePoint.

One thing is for sure, we'll be writing a lot of PowerShell in the next few years in order to update all those disjoined site collections

Comment: i know it is a grey area... and we are not at the best period to take decisions... but when we read about the benefits which are offered by modern sites and flat structures, we can not eliminate them and just go with the standard site collection/sub-suite,, i think we need to go for the modern Flatt structure and pay the price/effort (which seems it is a mandatory price/effort at this stage).. what do you think ?

Comment: second point,can you please give us some examples of the boundaries we might face when using modern team sites ?

Comment: This article sums it up nicely: http://digital.withum.com/blog/pros-and-cons-of-sharepoint-modern-sites

Comment: thanks for the reply. now from the link you provide seems the main limitation of using modern sites is that we can not have modern sub-sites.. But regarding the limitations on the UI, i think these limitations are also valid when using classic team sites, because in sharepoint online classic sites it is not recommended to provide custom master pages (although we can) , as customizing the master pages (for example customizing a copy of the seatle.html) might break in the future if SharePoint provides an update which is not compatible with our custom master page...

Comment: From my point of view the primary shortcomings are that you can no longer can inject js snipperts on the pages/lists without involving a developer to create a SPfx component and the fact that you will have to revert to classic if you are using any search based solutions as Modern does not cater for Search as we know it today

Comment: yes i know that modern site does not provide any tools to write code snippets, but the question will be :- **Is this an enough/sufficient reason to ignore using modern team sites?** At my end if i want to write JavaScript, i write them inside classic pages, then i embed the classic page inside modern pages using the Embed web part.. you can still write classic pages in modern team sites if you enabled publishing features, or you can create a classic team site which will contain all the classic pages you need.. this is a workaround and not necessary the best option to follow.

Comment: i mean i will not ignore using modern team sites just because i can not write code snippets inside modern pages